# Add item in array repeatedly for ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects which looks like:

```
{
    id: "1234",
    general: {
        title: "lorem",
        body: "..."
    }
}, ...
```

This data is being shown with an ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <h2>{{item.general.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.general.body}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what I want to achieve is to add items to this list. Every 15 items I want to add a new item to the array to display in my ng-repeat. The item has a different structure:

```
<li>
    <p>a text</p>
    <a>a link</a>
</li>
```

So far I got this in my controller:

```
var addLinks = function addLinks(interval, array) {

    var newArray = array.slice();

    for(var i = interval - 1; i < array.length; i += interval) {
        newArray.splice(i, 0, {
            // Here comes the item to add
        });
    }

    return newArray;
};

$scope.items = addLinks(15, articleService.articles);
```

My question is how do I add the item without just copying the html?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Any errors?

Comment: @AndreKreienbring Edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end and only add the other element if you are on $index+1 % 15, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="item in vm.array track by $index">{{item.a}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index>0 && $index+1 % 15 == 0"></li>
</ul>
```

Here a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qwkXGcBcxlDy0hNHTvAo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would add additional properties to the item in question:

```
var addLinks = function addLinks(interval, array) {
    //don't return a new array!
    //var newArray = array.slice();

    for(var i = interval - 1; i < array.length; i += interval) {
        array[i].text = "foo";
        array[i].link = "bar";
    }

    return array;
};
```

And in your view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <h2>{{item.general.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.general.body}}</p>

        <p ng-show="item.text">item.text</p>
        <p ng-show="item.link">item.link</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This also works but it required more work because my array of data comes from an api.